# Why does my 8-week-old son try to fit his fist up his nose?

Tags: behavior, newborn

My 8-week-old son tries to fit his fist up his nose (that's what it looks like). He makes a fist and forcefully pushes it toward his nose or just to the sides or under, shaking his head and making a grunting / growling sound. It is quite funny to watch. I've started to wonder what the heck he is actually trying to do...

Comment: +1 for a fantastic question name, made me laugh! Kids are crazy, get used to being baffled on a daily basis!

Answer (score 5):

Your son is getting used to moving his arms and exploring the world. Some handy advice can be found [here](http://www.whattoexpect.com/baby-behavior.aspx) and [here](http://www.secretsofbabybehavior.com/2009/10/babies-development-from-6-to-8-weeks.html).